# making sublots of multiplot graphs

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, regression

I'm working on linear regression of stocks and I want to have multiple graphs each of which shows, price, small moving average 30 and small moving average 100. I have gotten it so that I can either make 3 separate graphs each with the 3 plots on it, or 1 graph with all 9 plots on it, but I'm unable to make 1 graph that has 3 subplots each containing a plot for price, SMA30 and SMA100.

Here is my loop that gets me 3 different charts.

```
results = []
figure = []

data = len(ticker_list)

for i in range(data):
    df1=pd.read_csv('./data/'+str(files[i])+'.csv')
    col = (df1.columns)
    colPlot = (df1[col[5]])
    long_rolling = colPlot.rolling(window=100).mean()
    short_rolling = colPlot.rolling(window=30).mean()
    plt.plot(colPlot)
    plt.plot(long_rolling)
    plt.plot(short_rolling)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read the [matplotlib tutorial on subplots.](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Comment: I've read it, it shows how to make multiple single plot charts but not multiple multi-plot charts. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong in my loop but I'm not sure what.

Comment: `fig, axes = plt.subplots(n, m)` stores an n x m array of axis objects in `axes`. You can loop through it like through every other array. [See for example here where they zip the axis objects with another list](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-markevery-demo-py)